# Keycloak with react login page

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

We have very specific requirement, where we are going to have 2 types of authentication mechanism,
`username` & `password`
`username`(authentication will be done in mobile app by putting pin)

We have login page build in react, which is calling keycloak login by keycloak admin client, with this approach we are not able to maintain session so try to use keycloak session management, but when we try to use keycloak, I don't find any option to use existing login page.
We need to use keycloak's login page and customize it as per our need, but even we do that keycloak always require password to login.

NOTE:
We have custom `authenticator` to handle condition for password login or mobile app login.

Comment: That why Keycloak provide the customization of login page ,I will suggest use keycloak login page and customize it according to your requirement.